# UI like Cut the rope

Tags: android, user-interface, menu

I want to have a menu like that in the "Cut the rope" that come down with a rope like
[this](http://www.google.com/imgres?start=167&biw=1280&bih=735&tbm=isch&tbnid=vRTNcCC7m1jKhM%3a&imgrefurl=http://usergeneratededucation.wordpress.com/tag/game-based-learning/&docid=Jf8uIfUaDa7yaM&imgurl=http://usergeneratededucation.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/img_4027.jpg&w=1712&h=2152&ei=21x2UvfEJqnViwLqy4H4Dw&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:70,s:100,i:214&iact=rc&page=8&tbnh=189&tbnw=150&ndsp=23&tx=73&ty=82)

or like 
[this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wdc.wdremote) of course the last image

would you please help me?

or just say what I should google.

merci

Comment: Start with searching for something like "Adobe Illustrator" or other graphic programs.

Comment: I want android code for the UI not a way to design 
I want to know how to have a rope that when I pull it, a menu comes down

Comment: "I want android code" - what have you tried?

Comment: what do you mean?
I know some how about menus like dialog, progress and others
I want a name of course 
a name that I can google 

I didnt ask you to write the code
just a name to learn what the type is and search for it to be able to write!

Comment: by the way firstly I thought that is something like button but after that I found that it isnt 
because the rope itself move and rotate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu might be a simple `Dialog` or `View` that has an `Animation`. The rope is a number of `Bitmaps` that are shown one after another, which is another `Animation`.

I formatted all words you need to search for as `code`. I'm not sure if it is worth the work.

Comment: thank you very much
and do you know how the rope distinguish the direction of its rotation?

Comment: The rope is one if these details that nobody realizes but that takes a he'll lot of work. Think of a kind of film. As far as I have seen it, even the Down Animation and Up Animation use different ropes and bitmaps.